# What is the different between giving user root privileges and adding it to root's group

Tags: linux, centos, user, centos-7, sudoers

In Centos 7 I use visudo to grant root privileges, and I'm wondering what is the different between:
`myuser ALL=(ALL) ALL`

and

`# usermod -aG wheel myuser`

Comment: While the groop might have all the permissions of root, you can still take some of those permissions away, if you give each user in a group all of root's permissions you have that much work to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS seems to work slightly differently<sup>[[1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos)]</sup> from other Linux flavours.

By the way, in general

- With `# usermod -aG wheel myuser` you are adding `myuser` to the group of `wheel` <sup>[[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_%28Unix_term%29#Wheel_group)]</sup>, the CentOS equivalent of the group of `sudo` of many other Linux flavours.

  Then **you gain super user privileges through the ownership to a group** that have those privileges.

  **Note:** that should not be enough to gain the root privileges. You may manually have to add the `wheels` group in the `/etc/sudoers` file with `sudo visudo` adding the line

  ```
  %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
  ```
- With `myuser ALL=(ALL) ALL` **you are directly granting to `myuser` all the root privileges**.

  **Note:** You can grant a different set of privileges to `myuser` specifying rules different <sup>[[3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos#how-to-set-up-custom-rules)]</sup> from `ALL=(ALL) ALL`, simple or complex; for example: <sup>[[3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos#how-to-set-up-custom-rules)]</sup>

  ```
  UseRunas_Alias     WEB = www-data, apache
  GROUPTWO = brent, doris, eric, myuser
  GROUPTWO    ALL = (WEB) ALLr_Alias    

  # The next will deny to run /usr/bin/shutdown only to myuser
  # that maybe can still copy it with a different name 
  # and run from a different location ... 
  myuser      ALL = NOEXEC: /usr/bin/shutdown
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You run the command with root permissions and *drop back down* - as such if something else runs in the context of the user, it can't elevate itself. The difference is temporary permissions (as needed) vs permanent permissions.